# I can't understand this solution for finding span of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I can't understand this solution. Question asks for the span of $\{v_1,v_2\}$, given $v_1 = (2,3), v_2= (4,6)$.

I follow until the solution says:  $$\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}=\{(c+2d)(2,3) \mid c,d \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

Then it goes $=\{e(2,3) \mid e \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

I don't understand how $c+2d = e$?

Comment: $c+2d$ is real, since $c,d$ are too. Furthermore, the expression is capable of giving any real number.

Comment: omg that was so helpful... I was stuck on it thinking how is c+2d = e (2.71...). So they just replaced it with another random variable... correct?

Comment: Yes, $e$ has no special meaning here.